# TF2 Keras Load Model From Checkpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to load a model from checkpoint and continue training. My checkpoint callback is as follows,

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=filepath,
                         monitor=metric,
                         verbose=0,
                         mode=mode,
                         save_best_only=True)
```

then I can run model `fit` as follows,

```
model_history = model.fit(train_ds,
                          epochs=30,
                          validation_data=test_ds,
                          shuffle=True,
                          verbose=0, 
                          callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

`h5` file is saved in the correct folder with epoch and metric values in the file name. When `fit` completes. I would like to reload from the checkpoint and run for another N epochs using,

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(
    'models/2020_12_07_15_39_28___100-0.903.h5',
    custom_objects={'SparseCategoricalCrossEntropyMeanIoU': mean_iou,
                    'dice_coef': dice_coef_metric,
                    'combined_loss': loss_fn})
```

model does load and I can start training using `fit` however after one epoch during validation It gives and error,
`WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 256, 256, 3) for input Tensor("input_1_6:0", shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (256, 256, 3).`

Comment: I had a strange problem of a similar nature https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63953163/how-to-save-keras-custom-model-with-dynamic-input-shape-in-savemodel-format. I wrapped my model by Functional API and it worked

Comment: @Andrey Model is defined using the functional api